# how to pass reference of multidimensional map to a function with std::threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, reference

i wrote the code in following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
void hi (map<string,map<string,int> > &m ) {
   m["abc"]["xyz"] =1;
   cout<<"in hi";
}
int main() {
   map<string, map<string, int> > m;
   thread t = thread (hi, m);
   t.join();
   cout << m.size();
   return 0;
}
```

i passed 2D map m reference to hi function and i updated but it not reflecting in main function. When i print m.size() it printing zero only.how can i pass the 2D map reference to function using thread?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I am surprised your code compiles at all without the `std::ref`. It doesn't compile for me with GCC 4.7.3 or 4.8.0.

Comment: @juanchopanza gcc version 4.4.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thread constructor will copy its arguments, so one solution is to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
thread t = thread (hi, std::ref(m));
```

This creates a wrapper object that behaves as a reference. The wrapper itself will be copied (semantically, in reality the copy may be elided), but the underlying map will not. So overall, it will act as if you had passed by reference.